# How can I capture whats on the canvas on Tkinter to use on a Neural Network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tkinter, neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to build a program with Tkinter that lets the user draw on the canvas, click a button "Predict" and then feed an already trained Neural Network (MNIST database) with whatever is on the canvas.

How can I use that what is on the canvas as an image? Is it possible?

```
def paint(event):
x1, y1 = (event.x - 5), (event.y - 5)
x2, y2 = (event.x + 5), ( event.y + 5)
canvas.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black" )

root = Tk()

#///Menu///
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = menu)

top_frame = Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(side = TOP)
middle_frame_L = Frame(root)
middle_frame_L.pack(side = LEFT)
middle_frame_R = Frame(root)
middle_frame_R.pack(side = LEFT)

submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label = "Arquivo", menu = submenu)
submenu.add_command(label = "Sair", command = exit_program)

page_title = Label(top_frame, text = "MNIST Hand-Written Digit Classification", bg = "#adc9f7", font=("Helvetica", 30))
page_title.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)

instructions = Label(top_frame, text = "Desenhe no quadro abaixo um digito de 0 a 9. Após isso, clique em 'Prever' para a Rede Neural tentar acertar o seu número.", font = ("Helvetica", 15))
instructions.pack(side = BOTTOM)

canvas = Canvas(middle_frame_L, width = 200, height = 200, bg = "#8e8e8e")
canvas.pack()

prever_button = Button(middle_frame_L, text = "Prever", command = exit_program)
prever_button.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "Neural Network aleatória.png")
photo_label = Label(middle_frame_R, image = photo)
photo_label.pack(side = LEFT)

# bind mouse dragging event to Canvas
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+tkinter+save+canvas+image)?

Comment: Everytime you draw, you will use something like `canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1, ..., xn, yn, option, ...)`. This command will generate an id. So you can store this id into a list and access them with your neural code. The other way I can think of is to use the `tag` option in this command, then access all those drawn canvas items with the same tag.